KableExtra::footnote_marker_alphabet probelm
I am trying to add a footnote marker in my Rmarkdown file using the footnote_marker_alphabet. If I add only one footnote it works fine with escape=F under group_rows command. But when I add the footnote_marker_alphabet under multiple group_rows it shows the following error:
```
! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> First_draft.tex

Error: LaTeX failed to compile First_draft.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See First_draft.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I guess I know where's the problem. It is in the % sign that I am using in my second group_label. I guess it is somehow messing with the LaTeX output if use escape=F. Can someone please tell me the correct way of coding? Given that I want to include "%" sign in my group_label.
Here is the YAML I'm using:
```
---
title: Price setting
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{soul}
   - \usepackage{xcolor}
author:
  - name: Alice    
    email: alice@example.com
    affiliation: Stata banka
    correspondingauthor: true
    footnote: 1
  - name: Bob
    email: bob@example.com
    affiliation: Another University
address:
  - code: Some Institute of Technology
    organization: Big Wig University
    addressline: 1 main street
    city: Gotham
    state: State
    postcode: 123456
    country: United States
  - code: Another University
    organization: Department
    addressline: A street 29
    postcode: 2054 NX
    city: Manchester,
    country: The Netherlands
footnote:
  - code: 1
    text: "This is the first author footnote."
  - code: 2
    text: "Another author footnote."
abstract: |
  This is the abstract.
  It consists of two paragraphs.
keywords: 
  - keyword1
  - keyword2
journal: "An awesome journal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
classoption: preprint, 3p, authoryear
bibliography: mybibfile.bib
biblio-style: apalike
linenumbers: false
numbersections: true
# csl: https://www.zotero.org/styles/elsevier-harvard
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article

---
```

Here is the code that is giving me output1:
```
{r table1, echo=F }

load("table_4.rds")
freq_table<-ref_markt%>%
  add_row(percent_sales)%>%
  add_row(market.share.assessment)%>%
  add_row(main.costumer)%>%
  add_row(regular.customers1)%>%
  add_row(Competition)
knitr::kable(freq_table, caption="Market structure (percentages)",digits=0)%>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = paste0("The reference market for main product",footnote_marker_alphabet(1)), start_row = 1, end_row = 3,escape = F) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = paste0("% of turnover in Pakistan"), start_row = 4, end_row = 7) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = paste0("Market Share Assesment"), start_row = 8, end_row = 11)%>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Main customer", start_row = 12, end_row = 14) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Firm-customer relationship is long term", start_row = 15, end_row = 17)%>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Perceived degree of competition", start_row = 18, end_row = 22)%>%
  kableExtra::footnote(alphabet = c("note1"),alphabet_title = "Notes: ")
```

However, if I use the code 2 below, it gives me the error above:
```{r table1, echo=F }

load("table_4.rds")
freq_table<-ref_markt%>%
  add_row(percent_sales)%>%
  add_row(market.share.assessment)%>%
  add_row(main.costumer)%>%
  add_row(regular.customers1)%>%
  add_row(Competition)
knitr::kable(freq_table, caption="Market structure (percentages)",digits=0)%>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = paste0("The reference market for main product",footnote_marker_alphabet(1)), start_row = 1, end_row = 3,escape = F) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = paste0("% of turnover in Pakistan",footnote_marker_alphabet(1)), start_row = 4, end_row = 7,escape=F) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = paste0("Market Share Assesment"), start_row = 8, end_row = 11)%>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Main customer", start_row = 12, end_row = 14) %>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Firm-customer relationship is long term", start_row = 15, end_row = 17)%>% 
  kableExtra::group_rows(group_label = "Perceived degree of competition", start_row = 18, end_row = 22)%>%
  kableExtra::footnote(alphabet = c("note1"),alphabet_title = "Notes: ")
```

output1:

If anyone need any extra details please let me know
